# ¿Por qué no se dispara el evento onClick en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con React y tengo que renderizar una tabla, aquí el código que he trabajado:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => alert(":v")}>:v</button>
            <table id="tUsuarios" className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">No. Empleado</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Puesto</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.usuarios.map(user =>
                                <tr key={user.User}>
                                    <td>{user.User}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Name}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Empleado}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Mail}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Puesto}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href={"/Usuario?u=" + user.User} title={"Perfil de " + user.Name}><span className="fa fa-user fa-lg"></span></a>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <a href="#" onClick={() => alert(":v")}><span className="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></span></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

El problema es que, mientras el `button` que está hasta arriba sí lanza la alerta, ninguno de los enlaces en `this.state.usuarios.map` disparan el evento `onClick`.

Este código es el más sencillo que he intentado (ni siquiera haciendo binding ni nada, pasando una función ahí directamente) y ni siquera así funciona. ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué está pasando?

Comment: debes usar en tu boton el atributo onPress en ves de onClick

Comment: No se si es cosa mia pero, creo, sobran una llave y un parentesis justo debajo del </tr>

Comment: @JDavid no existe el evento `onPress`, pero ya intenté con MouseDown y nada.

Comment: @KubaHc sí, esto fue que borré el código que intenté con ECMA 5, al final poniendo el `.bind(this)` que se evita con ECMA 6 (`user =>`).

Comment: @Kroneaux Schneider claro, que torpe he sido, me he confundido con react-native.

Comment: Prueba con el atributo `onClick` onClick={this.sliderButtonsClick()}

Comment: ¿Te está mostrando los <a>? Porque tal y como está tendrás un <a> vacío (dentro del span no estás renderizando ningún texto) y lo único que muestras son las cabeceras.

Deberías tener algo así:
 `<a href="#" onClick={() => alert(":v")}><span className="fa fa-edit fa-lg" >{user}</span></a>`

Comment: Una confusión tan simple como esa se evita programando en vanillajs. Nada de frameworks o librerías de terceros. Yo llevo 10 años usando lenguajes en su forma "pura" y no me ha pasado nada. Incluso he creado mi propio servidor websocket y he implementado el algoritmo blowfish, todo desde cero y son conpletamente funcionales.

Answer (score 0):

Esta [Información](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) podría servirte para realizar la acción que necesitas.

Por ejemplo podrias intentar:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleButton}>Realizar</button>
```

Y el manejador de ese onClick seria:

```
handleButton(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("El mensaje que necesitas");
  return;
}
```

Si necesitas pasar un parametro desde el map que estas haciendo en el array para la información de la tabla debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<button type="button" onClick={(e) => this.handleButton(msm, e)}>Realizar</button>
```

Donde **msm** es el parametro que vas a recibir en el manejador.

```
handleButton(msm, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("El mensaje es: ${msm}
  return;
}
```

No te olvides de hacerle **bind** a la función del manejador en el constructor.

Saludos !